# DataStax Java Driver -- getDate does not return a timestamp

Tags: cassandra, client, datastax, datastax-java-driver

My code, which works on the 2.1 version of the driver, is failing on 2.2-rc2.

Here is the stacktrace:

```
Exception occurred in target VM: Value accountExpiryDate is of type timestamp 
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidTypeException: Value accountExpiryDate is of type timestamp
    at com.datastax.driver.core.AbstractGettableByIndexData.checkType(AbstractGettableByIndexData.java:75)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.AbstractGettableByIndexData.getDate(AbstractGettableByIndexData.java:192)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.AbstractGettableData.getDate(AbstractGettableData.java:26)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.AbstractGettableData.getDate(AbstractGettableData.java:113)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. I am sorry, but I am missing the question.

Comment: Can you create a patch that shows the difference?  That would help me understand what was changed.

Comment: Welcome! People have voted down you question as it doesn't seem to be a question. (It's a big report, right?) Also given that Cassandra is open source under active development it seems odd to post this code over here rather than log a bug over at Apache or seek out the emails lists that the developers use and ask them about it.

Answer (score 6):

I'm assuming you must be using 2.2.0-rc2 (given the presence of CodecRegistry) or using the 2.2 branch.   This isn't a bug, but I agree that it is pretty misleading.   Just to clarify, is there any code in the 2.2 documentation that indicates `getDate()` should work for `timestamp`?

In java-driver 2.0 and 2.1 `getDate()` [maps to the CQL `timestamp` type and returns a Date object](https://github.com/datastax/java-driver/blob/2.1.7/driver-core/src/main/java/com/datastax/driver/core/GettableByIndexData.java#L80-L90):

```java
/**
 * Returns the {@code i}th value as a date.
 *
 * @param i the index ({@code 0 <= i < size()}) to retrieve.
 * @return the value of the {@code i}th element as a data. If the
 * value is NULL, {@code null} is returned.
 *
 * @throws IndexOutOfBoundsException if {@code i} is not a valid index for this object.
 * @throws InvalidTypeException if value {@code i} is not of type TIMESTAMP.
 */
public Date getDate(int i);
```

However, in java-driver 2.2+ it instead maps to the `getDate()` [maps to the `date` type and returns a LocalDate object](https://github.com/datastax/java-driver/blob/2.2.0-rc2/driver-core/src/main/java/com/datastax/driver/core/GettableByIndexData.java#L116-L126):

```java
/**
 * Returns the {@code i}th value as a date (without time).
 *
 * @param i the index ({@code 0 <= i < size()}) to retrieve.
 * @return the value of the {@code i}th element as an date. If the
 * value is NULL, {@code null} is returned.
 *
 * @throws IndexOutOfBoundsException if {@code i} is not a valid index for this object.
 * @throws InvalidTypeException if value {@code i} is not of type DATE.
 */
public LocalDate getDate(int i);
```

This is because in cassandra 2.2 [new CQL types were added for `time` and `date`](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-2.2.0/doc/native_protocol_v4.spec#L597-L598).  It thus seemed appropriate in the driver to update the method definitions.   You can now retrieve `timestamp` types as `java.util.Date` objects by using [`getTimestamp()`](https://github.com/datastax/java-driver/blob/2.2.0-rc2/driver-core/src/main/java/com/datastax/driver/core/GettableByIndexData.java#L104-L114).  This change is documented in the [Upgrade Guide](http://datastax.github.io/java-driver/upgrade_guide/) for 2.2.0-rc2 under section #14:

```
Getters and setters have been added to “data-container” classes for new CQL types:

getByte/setByte for the TINYINT type
getShort/setShort for the SMALLINT type
getTime/setTime for the TIME type
getDate/setDate for the DATE type

The methods for the TIMESTAMP CQL type have been renamed to getTimestamp and setTimestamp.

This affects Row, BoundStatement, TupleValue and UDTValue.
```